# Will calling system command be faster than ruby method?

Tags: ruby, shell

I am writing a ruby script to compare large number of debian packages' version. I have two options here, using debian systems' `dpkg --compare-versions` from ruby script or implement the comparison routine in Ruby.

My question is which will be faster? Should I rely on `dpkg --compare-versions` or implement the algorithm?

Note: I am  assuming that the script will only be run from debian systems, though ability of running from non-debian system would be an extra benefit of course.

The version comparison algorithm is described here in [Ubuntu policy](http://people.canonical.com/~cjwatson/ubuntu-policy/policy.html/ch-controlfields.html#s-f-Version)

Comment: How often is this expected to be called? I say just use the dpkg command from the ruby script.

Comment: Very frequently. I've planned for using it with more than 10 thousands of packages' version. So, it will be called that number of times for a single execution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Ruby-Debian](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/ruby-debian) might also be an alternative. According to the description:

> ruby interface for dpkg
>
> This package provides Debian::Dpkg and Debian::DpkgDeb modules and
>   Debian::Deb, Debian::Dsc, Debian::Archives, Debian::Sources,
>   Debian::Packages and Debian::Status classes for ruby

(unfortunately, the web page doesn't contain examples on how to use this, so I guess your best bet is to install it and play with it in an irb/pry session).

**UPDATE**

Here's a complete example, as per the instructions by @Amadan (I had to use `require 'debian'` instead of `require 'ruby-debian'`)

*Installation*

```
apt-get install libapt-pkg-dev
gem install ruby-debian
```

*Usage*

```
require 'debian' 

puts Debian::Version.cmp_version("1.2.3", "<", "1.2.11")
```

Comment: Good find. I'll try it

Comment: Good find indeed. `apt-get install libapt-pkg-dev` and `gem install ruby-debian` should install it; then `require 'ruby-debian'` and `Debian::Version.cmp_version(ver1, "<", ver2)`. Calls native code directly from a library via compiled extension, does not call subprocesses. Obviously, only available on Debianish systems.

Comment: Nope, native means machine code (i.e. something compiled from C, assembly etc.) In this case, the Apt library.

Comment: So, there's not much difference if i call `dpkg --compare-versions` directly.

Comment: @Anwar Not quite. Both the ruby-debian gem (which uses the apt library ) and using `system("dpkg ...")` will use native code internally, but the `system` approach needs to start separate processes and therefore generates a (possibly substantial) overhead. I'd expect the gem version to be somewhat faster.

Comment: There is a lot of difference. Calling `dpkg` "directly" is not direct: it launches a subprocess, each time you do it. `ruby-debian` loads `libapt-pkg.so`, then executes the `CmpVersion` function just like it would execute any native Ruby function, by directly calling its implementation.

Comment: @Amadan That sounds great! I'll benchmark and report the result. +1 for now for Frank :)

Comment: http://pastebin.com/0cUskgWV

This is the benchmark result. First one using `dpkg --version-compare` and second one with ruby-debian gems.

Comment: Yup, not much difference at all :D (j/k)

Comment: There was a debian package called `ruby-debian`. That might be the debianized version of ruby-debian gem

Answer (score 2):

Considering that dpkg is written mostly in C, and that quite a bit of effort went into making it as fast as possible, I believe it would be best to call the command rather then try to implement the comparison yourself. Even if you manage to make the algorithm as efficient as the one dpkg uses, you would still have the speed gap between C and Ruby you won't be able to overcome.

However, there is some overhead to creating multiple processes. Since you want to compare thousands of versions, you might want to figure out a data structure and/or algorithm that allows you to make multiple comparisons at once (or reduce the number of comparisons needed). The viability of this  depends on your use case.

I would first try benchmarking with dpkg (as this doesn't require much work) and see if the runtime for it is fast enough for your requirements, before considering putting work into trying to optimize this.

Comment: Good hint. I'll do benchmarking then. Though, I might implement it for non-debian systems.